# php mysql + create a friend request system

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

i am creating a friend request system that allow user to send request to each other to add  as friends like facebook 
 and i have 2 conditions that if :

- the user is the profile owner he can not add him self i will echo an
  error msg
- the user is not the owner of the profile it will echo a message that
  say wait then the request is send

if the user has already send the request i will echo a message to infor the user that a request had been send.

but the error is that i am  in the first condition because the system display that the user is the owner profile but this is wrong

can anyone help me ??

## this is a chunk of code

```
function addAsFriend(a,b){
   //alert("Member with id:" + a + "request friendship with the memeber with id:" + b);
  var url = "script_for_profile/request_as_friend.php";
  $("#add_friend").text("please wait...").show();
  $.post(url,{request:"requestFreindship",mem1:a,mem2:b},function(data){
    $("#add_friend").html(data).show().fadeOut(12000);
  });
}

<div class="interactContainers" id="add_friend">
               <div align="right"><a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers('add_friend');">Cancel</a></div>
               Add <?php echo $username ?> as Friend?&nbsp;
               <a href ="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:addAsFriend(<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>,<?php echo $userid; ?>);">Yes</a>
```

## request_as_friend.php

```
<?php
//var we need for  both  members
$mem1=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_POST['mem1']);
$mem2=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_POST['mem2']);

if(!$mem1||!$mem2)
{
    echo "Error .missing data";
    exit();
}
if($mem1==$mem2)
{
    echo "Error you can not add yourself as friend";
    exit();
}
 require_once('../include/connect.php'); 


 if($_POST['request']=="requestFriendship")
 {
     //check that  there  is not  a request  pending  where this viewer  is requesting  this profile  owner
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id  FROM friend_requests WHERE mem1='$mem1' AND mem2='$mem2'limit1")or die(mysql_error());
     $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
     if($numRows > 0)
     {
         echo "You have a friend request pending already  for this member. they must approve  it when they view their request list";
         exit();
     }
      //check that  there  is not  a request  pending  where this profile owner  is not already requesting  this viewer
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id  FROM friend_requests WHERE mem1='$mem2' AND mem2='$mem1'limit1")or die(mysql_error());
     $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
     if($numRows > 0)
     {
         echo "This user has requested you as friend already! Check  your friend  Request on your profile";
         exit();
     }
     $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO friend_requests(mem1,mem2,timedate) VALUES('$mem1','$mem2',now())") or die (mysql_error("friend request  insertionn error"));
     //$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pms(to,from,time,sub,msg) VALUES('$mem2','XXXXX',now(),'New Friend Request','YOU Have a New  friend request waiting for approval.<br /><br />Navigate to your profile and check  your friend request.<br /><br />Thank you.')") or die (mysql_error("friend request PM insertionn error"));

  echo "Friend Request  sent  succesfully. this member must approve the request";
  exit();    
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was totally wrong, you don't need to create any extra flag, just store the `user_id` -*which you retrieve from the database when the user logs in* - store it in the session then when he/she clicks on the **add friend** button check the `$_SESSION['user_id']` with the id of the other user before completing the friendship function, if they're both the same, means it's the same person, otherwise add friends.

Comment: and how to use it here ?? i mean i add the boolean field in the database then i will check in the php   correct to me if i am wrong

Comment: you can store its value in the session after retrieving it from the database when the user logs-in to the system, although this has some security issue concerning session hijacking, you can check on its value before -adding the friend-

Comment: this what  i must do :  create $is_owner = 0;    after the sql query i add $_SESSION['isowner'] = 1;    then  i use this session in the profile page

Comment: @user2338686 No no sorry i was wrong, check my updated answer, I apologize again

Comment: i did stored the user_id in a session    so what i need to do as you say is to check if the SESSION['user_id'] = $userid ????   so i do the check before  [[Add <?php echo $username ?> as Friend?&nbsp;
               <a href ="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:addAsFriend(<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>,<?php echo $userid; ?>);">Yes</a>]]                                                        i did not understand what you mean???

Comment: @user2338686 ,Which part you didn't understand.. Now let's suppose userX is browsing the network -*means you have his id stored in his session*- and he enters userY's profile page, he likes and clicks on the **add friend** button, now before accepting you compare userX_id from his session with userY's id. I'm supposing you already retrieved userY's data from the database including his/her id since it is his/her profile webpage which contains his/her info. now if `$_SESSION['userX_id'] = $userYid` then they’re the same person, if not the same, call the addingFriends function.

Comment: You can even make further use of this, if `$_SESSION['userX_id'] = $userYid` then you can hide the add button since he is on his own profile!

Answer (score -1):

What the post array returns for mem1 and mem2?

However, you shouldn't compare the post data. Or not both.

For example you have logged in, your id is stored in session. You are opening a user profile i.e.: http://yoursite.com/viewprofile.php?id=1001 . Then after passing from the jquery you should check in PHP smth like:

```
if ($_GET['id'] = $_SESSIOM['id']) {
   //you cannot add yourself
}
```

Comment: the system display that the user id is the same as the session['user_id'] but this is wrong

Comment: dumping the session and the request returns equal id's?